# Is there a way to have column values in a DataFrame update automatically when other columns are updated

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to have a column in a Dataframe update automatically when an original entry in the Dataframe is modified?  Suppose I have the following:

```
dataset=({'A':[1,2,3]})
df=pd.DataFrame(dataset)
df['B']=df['A'].cumprod()

In: df

Out[257]: 
   A    B
0  1    1
1  2    2
2  3    6
```

If I change a values in A

```
df.iloc[1,0]=4
```

Column B does not change.

```
In: df
Out[260]: 
     A    B
0    1    1
1    4    2
2    3    6
```

I am wondering whether there is some way to define B so that I would get:

```
Out[260]: 
     A    B
0    1    1
1    4    4
2    6    24
```

I saw an answer on a thread from 2013 that said this functionality would be added, but can't seem to find anything other documentation on it.  I have tried using pd.eval but that doesn't seem to have this functionality.

Comment: call it again maybe ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, i'll edit the question.  Sorry I'm still learning the ways of python and stackoverflow.  What I meant was is that the only way?  I was trying to avoid that because the actual dataset contains over 50,000 rows and an adjustment in a single column  effects the value of a series of other columns.  I wanted to know if it was possible to avoid having to call all of them a series of times.  Furthermore if the first change occurs in say row i, i didn't want to recalculate the values above row i.

Comment: Asssuming you have the index at which the change is made. use `loc` to get the rows ahead of it and assign the value to column `B` for those rows only.

Comment: Honestly it wont really matter if the formula for calculation of `B` remains the same after the value changes. Unless its a performance issue.